# How do I create a monolithic (display individual items) from my data base? php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a page which displays news articles. For styling purposes and to add consistency to the page, I have cut the text to a certain number of characters. I would now like to display the data connected to each specific piece of data on a separate page. How would I do this?

```
 function custom_echo($x, $length)
 {
   if(strlen($x)<=$length)
   {
     echo $x;
   }
   else
   {
     $y=substr($x,0,$length) . ' ...Read More';
     echo $y;
   }
 }

 $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
 $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
   echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news">';
   echo '<p class="news-title">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'</p>';

   echo '<img class="news-img" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $results[$i     ]['logo'] ).'"/>';
   echo '<p class="news-time">'.$results[$i]['date'].'<br>'.'</p>';
   echo ('<p class="news-body">');
   custom_echo ($results[$i]['text'], 360);  
   echo '<br>'.'</p>'.'</div>';
 }
```

Comment: You would pass the id to a different script as a GET parameter, `displaydetails.php?id=123`, and then inside that script you would use that parameter to get the details of that specific article from the database ...

Comment: what do you mean passing the id to a different script? Thanks for answering. @CBroe

Comment: Well you create a link, and pass the id in a form similar to what I have shown ... If you do not know what GET parameters are, and how to handle them in PHP, then please go read up on that.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will read into this and try this out. Thank you @CBroe

Comment: @CBroe I cannot find any information on this, would you be able to show me an example please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22452325/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18288469/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27708520/1427878

Comment: Nope. StackOverflow is not a write-code-for-me type of site. We are happy to help you with specific details ... but if you want to program, you need to go and learn some of the necessary basics yourself first.

Comment: @CBroe okay.. I have created a second page called fullarticles.php, I have managed to create a simple form which can post information form one to the other. But honestly I am confused in how I can show the data from the database?

Comment: Well you take the id value that was passed to the script, and create the appropriate SQL statement to select only the record with that specific id ... You know what a WHERE clause is, right? (And if not, we are coming back again to the fact that you need to go an learn some _basics_ first. There’s lots of tutorials, books and explanations out there for that.)